# Set Background to canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

how i can set background on string path?

```
canvas1.Background = "/path/";
```

please help!!! thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for the [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx) class:

```
ImageBrush imageBrush = new ImageBrush();
imageBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/path/", UriKind.Relative));
canvas1.Background = imageBrush;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
mycanvas.Background = new ImageBrush() 
          { ImageSource = new BitmapImage((new Uri(mypath, UriKind.Absolute))) };
```