# Save div to image after drag and drop

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a webpage with asp.net/c# where I can drag images from one div to another with HTML5. Now I need to save the resulting div as an image. It has to work in Firefox and Chrome.

I already tried this:

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

[Convert webpage to image from ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715385/convert-webpage-to-image-from-asp-net)

Those capture the page without the dragged elements.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1443600.aspx

This just shows a black box.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to have bothered you all, but now I got the answer by myself!
The problem was that the image-elements where still in the dragzone in the DOM, so they didn't show up in the image. This is how I solved it:

```
<div id="dragzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="drag_over(event)" style="width:100%; height: 572px;">

    <img id="dragme" src="Images\ballgreen.png" draggable="true" style="position:absolute; left: 36px; top: 210px;" ondragstart="drag_start(event)">
    <img id="img2" src="Images\ballred.png" draggable="true" style="position:absolute; left: 36px; top: 220px;" ondragstart="drag_start(event)" >
</div>

<div id="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="drag_over(event)" style="width:500px;height:500px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa; background-color: #ccccff;">

<script>
    function drag_start(event) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null);
        var data = (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"), 10) - event.clientX)
            + ',' + (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"), 10) - event.clientY)
            + ',' + event.target.id;
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", data);
    }
    function drag_over(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    function drop(event) {
        var offset = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain").split(',');
        var id = offset[2];
        var dragzone = document.getElementById('dragzone');
        var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
        var dm = document.getElementById(id);

        if (dm != null) {
            dragzone.removeChild(dm);
            dropzone.appendChild(dm);
            dm.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(offset[0], 10)) + 'px';
            dm.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(offset[1], 10)) + 'px';
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    function screenshots() {
        var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
        html2canvas(dropzone, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
                var test = 'test';
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think , you already have partial answer to this query as you have link for converting Canvas into an image.

You can use the link http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/ as you have already mentioned.
Now, the main problem is to set the image in Canvas.

I think you should set the image as a background of Canvas and then convert the Canvas into image.

To set the background image of Canvas refer the below URL
[Set Background to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992853/set-background-to-canvas)

This will help you to save the resulting Canvas(diV) as an image..